# Objective C Compile Time CRC Generation and Checking

Tags: xcode, xcode7, crc

I'm using Objective C with the native webkit GUI option for my Cocoa-based application, and using `file://` URLs to load my GUI. Is there a way that at compile time I can generate a CRC value on my html folder and save it in a plist so that when the application loads, it can validate the CRC to ensure the directory hasn't been tampered with since the HTML is plain text and modifiable?

I know that I can manually do this with a Bash script, but wanted to know how to setup XCode to do this during compiling.

Note: Of course I would kind of sha256 hash or AES256 encrypt this with a salt so that someone couldn't just generate their own very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a script for this, you can simply create a run script phase for this build target and put add the script to it.